# How to write a string with escaped \n to a file

Tags: python

Say I have a json file like

```
{"text":"Here is a string\nhere is another string","timestamp":"2021-05-24"}
```

I am trying to load it to a file and write the text field down, so the output file will be exactly

```
Here is a string\nhere is another string
```

However, if I read it as a json and do something like `out.write(j['text'])`, I will get

```
Here is a string
here is another string
```

in the file, which translates `\n` into a new line. Is there a way I could output the string in the desired way?

Comment: Did you try escape sequence \. like \\n ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however you would need to escape the `\` in your string. Try using `str.replace('\n', '\\n')`. However, this would not work in cases where you would want to have `\n` somewhere else in the string.

Comment: This could cause problems if they have other uses of backslash in the text that they did not intend to escape.

Comment: Since it is difficult to distinguish when you want `\n` as `\n` and when as newline character, replacing `\n` with `\\n` seems to be the right approach until then.